# Wrong order of items in legend (Google Chrome issue)

Tags: google-chrome, highcharts

I have problem with items order in legend, when I using Google Chrome browser and when I have more than 10 items. In all other browsers items are displayed in appropriate order, but in Chrome - not.

version: Highcharts JS v2.1.6 (2011-07-08)
Chrome versions: 19.0.1084.56 and 20.0.1132.47

The chart looks like below:

[image]

Please see following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="highcharts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chart',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    size: '80%',
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false,
                        color: '#000000',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                        distance: 10                
                    },
                showInLegend: true
                }
            },
            legend: {
                itemWidth: 100
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                data: [
                            ['label1', 10],        
                            ['label2', 20],
                            ['label3', 30],
                            ['label4', 40],
                            ['label5', 155.89],
                            ['label6', 50],
                            ['label7', 60],
                            ['label8', 70],
                            ['label9', 80],
                            ['label10', 90],
                            ['label11', 65.70],
                            ['label12', 100],
                    ]
                }]
            });
        });

</script>
<div id="chart" style="width: 460px; height: 290px; margin: 0 auto">

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: update highcharts library to 2.2.5.